# Access 2016 Switchboard convert macro to vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

On an Access 2016 Switchboard I converted the macro behind the form to VBA but it wouldn't compile. A band-aid solution I found was to add **.Value** to **TempVars.Add "CurrentItemNumber", ItemNumber** and change both instances of **Call Argument & "()"** to **Call Eval(Argument & "()")**. This solved the compile error.

I then added another button "Reports Menu" to the Switchboard but when I click on the new button I get this error.

[image]

When I click Debug it highlights this line **TempVars.Add "SwitchboardID", Argument**. When I added **.Value** to the end of this line **TempVars.Add "SwitchboardID", Argument.Value** it solved the breakpoint issue and the new button works but now the Report Menu does not fill in properly.

[image]

I can click Return To Main to get back to the Main Menu and all other buttons on the Main Menu work fine except the new Reports Menu Button.

Here is the code behind the switchboard...

```
    Option Compare Database

'------------------------------------------------------------
' Form_Current
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Form_Current()
On Error GoTo Form_Current_Err

  'TempVars.Add "CurrentItemNumber", ItemNumber
  TempVars.Add "CurrentItemNumber", ItemNumber.Value

Form_Current_Exit:
  Exit Sub

Form_Current_Err:
  MsgBox Error$
  Resume Form_Current_Exit

End Sub


'------------------------------------------------------------
' Form_Open
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo Form_Open_Err

  TempVars.Add "SwitchboardID", DLookup("SwitchboardID", "Switchboard Items", "[ItemNumber] = 0 AND [Argument] = 'Default'")
  DoCmd.SetProperty "Label1", acPropertyCaption, DLookup("ItemText", "Switchboard Items", "[SwitchboardID] = " & TempVars("SwitchboardID"))
  DoCmd.SetProperty "Label2", acPropertyCaption, DLookup("ItemText", "Switchboard Items", "[SwitchboardID] = " & TempVars("SwitchboardID"))
  DoCmd.Requery ""


Form_Open_Exit:
  Exit Sub

Form_Open_Err:
  MsgBox Error$
  Resume Form_Open_Exit

End Sub


'------------------------------------------------------------
' Option1_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Option1_Click()
On Error GoTo Option1_Click_Err

  On Error GoTo 0
  If (Command = 1) Then
    'TempVars.Add "SwitchboardID", Argument
    TempVars.Add "SwitchboardID", Argument.Value
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label1", acPropertyCaption, DLookup("ItemText", "Switchboard Items", "[SwitchboardID] = " & TempVars("SwitchboardID"))
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label2", acPropertyCaption, DLookup("ItemText", "Switchboard Items", "[SwitchboardID] = " & TempVars("SwitchboardID"))
    DoCmd.Requery ""
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 2) Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm Argument, acNormal, "", "", acAdd, acNormal
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 3) Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm Argument, acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 4) Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport Argument, acViewReport, "", "", acNormal
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 5) Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSwitchboardManager
    TempVars.Add "SwitchboardID", DLookup("SwitchboardID", "Switchboard Items", "[ItemNumber] = 0 AND [Argument] = 'Default'")
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label1", acPropertyCaption, DLookup("ItemText", "Switchboard Items", "[SwitchboardID] = " & TempVars("SwitchboardID"))
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label2", acPropertyCaption, DLookup("ItemText", "Switchboard Items", "[SwitchboardID] = " & TempVars("SwitchboardID"))
    DoCmd.Requery ""
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 6) Then
    DoCmd.CloseDatabase
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 7) Then
    DoCmd.RunMacro Argument, , ""
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 8) Then
    'Call Argument & "()"
    Call Eval(Argument & "()")
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Beep
  MsgBox "Unknown option.", vbOKOnly, ""


Option1_Click_Exit:
  Exit Sub

Option1_Click_Err:
  MsgBox Error$
  Resume Option1_Click_Exit

End Sub


'------------------------------------------------------------
' OptionLabel1_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub OptionLabel1_Click()
On Error GoTo OptionLabel1_Click_Err

  On Error GoTo 0
  If (Command = 1) Then
    'TempVars.Add "SwitchboardID", Argument
    TempVars.Add "SwitchboardID", Argument.Value
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label1", acPropertyCaption, DLookup("ItemText", "Switchboard Items", "[SwitchboardID] = " & TempVars("SwitchboardID"))
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label2", acPropertyCaption, DLookup("ItemText", "Switchboard Items", "[SwitchboardID] = " & TempVars("SwitchboardID"))
    DoCmd.Requery ""
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 2) Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm Argument, acNormal, "", "", acAdd, acNormal
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 3) Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm Argument, acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 4) Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport Argument, acViewReport, "", "", acNormal
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 5) Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSwitchboardManager
    TempVars.Add "SwitchboardID", DLookup("SwitchboardID", "Switchboard Items", "[ItemNumber] = 0 AND [Argument] = 'Default'")
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label1", acPropertyCaption, DLookup("ItemText", "Switchboard Items", "[SwitchboardID] = " & TempVars("SwitchboardID"))
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label2", acPropertyCaption, DLookup("ItemText", "Switchboard Items", "[SwitchboardID] = " & TempVars("SwitchboardID"))
    DoCmd.Requery ""
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 6) Then
    DoCmd.CloseDatabase
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 7) Then
    DoCmd.RunMacro Argument, , ""
    Exit Sub
  End If
  If (Command = 8) Then
    'Call Argument & "()"
    Call Eval(Argument & "()")
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Beep
  MsgBox "Unknown option.", vbOKOnly, ""


OptionLabel1_Click_Exit:
  Exit Sub

OptionLabel1_Click_Err:
  MsgBox Error$
  Resume OptionLabel1_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `Argument` there? A text box?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. This is a Switchboard so they are command buttons. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Can you add an `Option Explicit` to top of your module and recompile -

Comment: what is `Argument` - is that a global

Comment: I added Option Explicit to the very top and compiled but the same error comes up when clicking the new button.

Comment: Not sure what Argument is. This code was created by Access when it converted the macros to VBA.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if it would have been better to stay with the default embedded macros created by the Switchboard Manager instead of converting it to VBA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate the responses but due to time constrains I threw in the towel trying to fix this code that was generated by Access 2016 (when it converted the macros) and grabbed Switchboard from code from an older database that works. I believe that code was created with Access 2003 but it still works perfectly (see below) It has a limit of 8 buttons per switchboard but it should be enough for most applications.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
' Minimize the database window and initialize the form.

' Move to the switchboard page that is marked as the default.
Me.Filter = "[ItemNumber] = 0 AND [Argument] = 'Default' "
Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
' Update the caption and fill in the list of options.

Me.Caption = Nz(Me![ItemText], "")
FillOptions

End Sub

Private Sub FillOptions()
' Fill in the options for this switchboard page.

' The number of buttons on the form.
Const conNumButtons = 8

Dim con As Object
Dim RS As Object
Dim stSql As String
Dim intOption As Integer

' Set the focus to the first button on the form,
' and then hide all of the buttons on the form
' but the first.  You can't hide the field with the focus.
Me![Option1].SetFocus
For intOption = 2 To conNumButtons
    Me("Option" & intOption).Visible = False
    Me("OptionLabel" & intOption).Visible = False
Next intOption

' Open the table of Switchboard Items, and find
' the first item for this Switchboard Page.
Set con = Application.CurrentProject.Connection
stSql = "SELECT * FROM [Switchboard Items]"
stSql = stSql & " WHERE [ItemNumber] > 0 AND [SwitchboardID]=" & Me![SwitchboardID]
stSql = stSql & " ORDER BY [ItemNumber];"
Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open stSql, con, 1   ' 1 = adOpenKeyset

' If there are no options for this Switchboard Page,
' display a message.  Otherwise, fill the page with the items.
If (RS.EOF) Then
    Me![OptionLabel1].Caption = "There are no items for this switchboard page"
Else
    While (Not (RS.EOF))
        Me("Option" & RS![ItemNumber]).Visible = True
        Me("OptionLabel" & RS![ItemNumber]).Visible = True
        Me("OptionLabel" & RS![ItemNumber]).Caption = RS![ItemText]
        RS.MoveNext
    Wend
End If

' Close the recordset and the database.
RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
Set con = Nothing

End Sub

Private Function HandleButtonClick(intBtn As Integer)
' This function is called when a button is clicked.
' intBtn indicates which button was clicked.

' Constants for the commands that can be executed.
Const conCmdGotoSwitchboard = 1
Const conCmdOpenFormAdd = 2
Const conCmdOpenFormBrowse = 3
Const conCmdOpenReport = 4
Const conCmdCustomizeSwitchboard = 5
Const conCmdExitApplication = 6
Const conCmdRunMacro = 7
Const conCmdRunCode = 8
Const conCmdOpenPage = 9

' An error that is special cased.
Const conErrDoCmdCancelled = 2501

Dim con As Object
Dim RS As Object
Dim stSql As String

On Error GoTo HandleButtonClick_Err

' Find the item in the Switchboard Items table
' that corresponds to the button that was clicked.
Set con = Application.CurrentProject.Connection
Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
stSql = "SELECT * FROM [Switchboard Items] "
stSql = stSql & "WHERE [SwitchboardID]=" & Me![SwitchboardID] & " AND [ItemNumber]=" & intBtn
RS.Open stSql, con, 1    ' 1 = adOpenKeyset

' If no item matches, report the error and exit the function.
If (RS.EOF) Then
    MsgBox "There was an error reading the Switchboard Items table."
    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    Exit Function
End If

Select Case RS![Command]

    ' Go to another switchboard.
    Case conCmdGotoSwitchboard
        Me.Filter = "[ItemNumber] = 0 AND [SwitchboardID]=" & RS![Argument]

    ' Open a form in Add mode.
    Case conCmdOpenFormAdd
        DoCmd.OpenForm RS![Argument], , , , acAdd

    ' Open a form.
    Case conCmdOpenFormBrowse
        DoCmd.OpenForm RS![Argument]

    ' Open a report.
    Case conCmdOpenReport
        DoCmd.OpenReport RS![Argument], acPreview

    ' Customize the Switchboard.
    Case conCmdCustomizeSwitchboard
        ' Handle the case where the Switchboard Manager
        ' is not installed (e.g. Minimal Install).
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Run "ACWZMAIN.sbm_Entry"
        If (Err <> 0) Then MsgBox "Command not available."
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Update the form.
        Me.Filter = "[ItemNumber] = 0 AND [Argument] = 'Default' "
        Me.Caption = Nz(Me![ItemText], "")
        FillOptions

    ' Exit the application.
    Case conCmdExitApplication
        CloseCurrentDatabase

    ' Run a macro.
    Case conCmdRunMacro
        DoCmd.RunMacro RS![Argument]

    ' Run code.
    Case conCmdRunCode
        Application.Run RS![Argument]

    ' Open a Data Access Page
    Case conCmdOpenPage
        DoCmd.OpenDataAccessPage RS![Argument]

    ' Any other command is unrecognized.
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Unknown option."

End Select

' Close the recordset and the database.
RS.Close

HandleButtonClick_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
Set RS = Nothing
Set con = Nothing
Exit Function

HandleButtonClick_Err:
' If the action was cancelled by the user for
' some reason, don't display an error message.
' Instead, resume on the next line.
If (Err = conErrDoCmdCancelled) Then
    Resume Next
Else
    MsgBox "There was an error executing the command.", vbCritical
    Resume HandleButtonClick_Exit
End If

End Function
```

Hope this can help someone else...

Answer (score 1):

In Access 365, there seem to be two errors in the conversion of Switchboard macros to VBA: one in the **On Current** Event Procedure and one the **On Open** Event Procedure. The error message points to only to the **On Open** procedure, while the the **On Current** event procedure seems to also need to be changed.

**On Current:**  This generates Run Time Error 32538 "TempVars can only store data. They cannot store objects.". 
Change **TempVars.Add "CurrentItemNumber", ItemNumber** to
**TempVars.Add "CurrentItemNumber", ItemNumber.Value**.

**On Open:** This generates the compile error. 
Change all instances of **Call Argument & "()"** to **Eval (Argument & "()")**.
Although not necessary, but good coding practice, change all the DoCmd statements that have **Argument** to **Argument.Value**.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Some critique of your code:

1. `Call Eval(Argument & "()")` doesn't make any sense. The `Call` is redundant; `Eval(Argument & "()")` is what really calls the function name in `Argument`. Try `Application.Run Me.Argument.Value` instead.
2. You should fully specify all control values in your code. Examples: `Me.Command.Value`, `Me.Argument.Value`, `Me.ItemNumber.Value`, etc.
3. Instead of `DoCmd.SetProperty "Label1", acPropertyCaption, "caption"`, use: `Me.Lable1.Caption = "caption"`
4. In every case, there is no need to set `Lable2` using the same `DLookup` function as `Label1`. Simply use `Me.Label2.Caption = Me.Label1.Caption`
5. Instead of `TempVars.Add "SwitchboardID", Argument`, it is probably cleaner to write `TempVars("SwitchboardID") = Me.Argument.Value`

This will help you get to your goals, but I can't guarantee this will fix your problems. You will have to use traditional debugging methods to find out what else might be going wrong, and fix it.

Comment: @JohnC: did you give up, or are you still working on your VBA switchboard code?